# How to load Spring Application Context in Non Main method

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, aws-lambda

I want to load Spring initial context inside a AWS lambda handler class. This class is the starting point of my application. I did it in the below way.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<KinesisEvent, Object> {

@Override
  public Object handleRequest(KinesisEvent input, Context context) {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(LambdaFunctionHandler.class);
    LambdaFunctionHandler lambdaHandlerBean = appContext.getBean(LambdaFunctionHandler.class);
    // some business logic call
    return null;
  }

}
```

This is working fine but I'm getting warning on appContext that it should be closed as it is resource leak. this can be fixed by calling appContext.close() but my doubt is whether this way of initializing Spring application context in a non main method is correct ? Most recommended way to do in a main method is like below

```
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(LambdaFunctionHandler.class);
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = app.run(args);
LambdaFunctionHandler lambdaFunctionHandler = 
context.getBean(LambdaFunctionHandler.class);
```

But I don't have the value to replace the args in my case. can anyone suggest the right way of doing this

Comment: Can you just `@Inject`/`@Authowired` LambdaFunctionHandler into your app. Create a separate configuration file and move `@SpringBootApplication`to the main class.

Comment: @AntonNovopashin on AWS Lambda the handler function is the "main". It's the application entry point.

Comment: @MarkB Yeah you are right, I jumped  too. AWS is kinda different animal and per my understanding...

Answer (score 0):

You can simple class with main method for @SpringBootApplication and
use CommandLineRunner for loading AWS lambda handler. Just implement the run to load the bean

1. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html

Comment: Thanks for the response.But commandLiner didnt worked. When the AWS Lambda function is triggered, the handleRequest() is invoked and it is the entry point of the application. hence even though if the class implements the CommandLiner and if I initialize the application context inside the overrided run() it wont help as the handleRequest() will get invoked before the run()